# List<Button> - Botones Dinamicos

Tags: asp.net

Estoy hacienda una aplicacion en la que tengo varios botones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi intension es crear una lista de botones para hacerlos dinamicos. entiendase por que le quiero colocar los numeros mostrados con informacion que se tiene de un archivo XML ya serializado y deserealizado

mi unica duda es **¿como puedo crear la lista de botones?**

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>(); ¿que seguiria?
```

En mi archive XML obtengo los siguientes datos

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<ArrayOfArea xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


-<Area>

<TOOL>MAK-1234</TOOL>

<AREA>FCH</AREA>

<POOL>Pool 30</POOL>

<TEAM>514</TEAM>

<STATION>1020</STATION>

<OPERATION>Apriete pedal del clutch</OPERATION>

<TORQUE>30</TORQUE>

<TL_NAME>cesar</TL_NAME>

<STATUS>Ok</STATUS>

<STANDBY>1</STANDBY>

<REG_DATE>Monday, June 19, 2017</REG_DATE>

</Area>


-<Area>

<TOOL>SAM-15946</TOOL>

<AREA>FCH</AREA>

<POOL>Pool 30</POOL>

<TEAM>514</TEAM>

<STATION>1020</STATION>

<OPERATION>Apriete pedal del clutch</OPERATION>

<TORQUE>30</TORQUE>

<TL_NAME>Carlos</TL_NAME>

<STATUS>Ok</STATUS>

<STANDBY>1</STANDBY>

<REG_DATE>Monday, June 19, 2017</REG_DATE>

</Area>


-<Area>

<TOOL>NAÑM-46</TOOL>

<AREA>FCH</AREA>

<POOL>Pool 30</POOL>

<TEAM>515</TEAM>

<STATION>1020</STATION>

<OPERATION>Apriete de pedal</OPERATION>

<TORQUE>30</TORQUE>

<TL_NAME>Carmelo</TL_NAME>

<STATUS>OK</STATUS>

<STANDBY>0</STANDBY>

<REG_DATE>Monday, June 19, 2017</REG_DATE>

</Area>

</ArrayOfArea>
```

en los botones iria lo que viene siendo "TEAM" y `STANDBY` con valor a 0
 hago las diferentes consultas al archivo XML

Hasta el momento llevo este codigo, ya que me he detenido por la cuestion de la lista de botones

```
//deserealizada
            List<Data.Area> ListOfEquipo = new List<Data.Area>();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfEquposFCHOk = ListOfEquipo.Where(x => x.AREA == "FCH" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            var TeamFCH = ListOfEquposFCHOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

            if (true)
            {

            }

            foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61001/discussion-on-question-by-cesar-gutierrez-davalos-listbutton-botones-dinamic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que "TeamFCH" es la lista donde almacenas los "Teams" que quieres aplicar en los botones

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>(); 

foreach(var item in TeamFCH)
{
   Button newButton = new Button();
   newButton.Number = item; //Estoy tomando "number" como el atributo de tu boton donde ira el numero, seguro lo tienes distinto, posiblemente hasta tengas que hacer un parseo
   buttons.Add(newButton);
}
```

Una vez haya terminado esto, tendras tu lista de botones.

**EDITADO:** Hago este comentario para quienes vean esto más adelante, lo de arriba resuelve la duda de la pregunta, sin embargo no es óptimo que todos los botones estén creados en duro y que se muestren o no segun la cantidad de "teams", lo ideal es que tambien se creen dinámicamente.

Comment: algo que habia olvidado (lo siento) cuando obtengo informacion de la lista lo hago de la siguiente manera

Comment: `List<Data.Area> ListOfEquipo = new List<Data.Area>();`   `list<Data.Area> ListOfEquposFCHOk = ListOfEquipo.Where(x => x.AREA == "FCH" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();`  `var TeamFCH = ListOfEquposFCHOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: podrias incluirlo en la pregunta, para verlo con mas claridad? (y asi los que encuentren esto mas adelante tambien lo entiendan mejor)

Comment: Claro que si, ya edite mi pregunta y coloque lo que llevo de codigo aunque como afirmo, me he detenido por lo de la lista de botones

Comment: cuando dices "dinamicamente" quieres decir que se creen por medio de un ciclo (en algun momento lo tuve de esa manera)

Comment: el ejemplo de crear botones por medio de un ciclo, lo tome de esta pagina http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-create-array-of-buttons-with-common-event-handler

Comment: Si, o tambien podrias crearlos segun la cantidad de elementos de TeamFCH, pero ya que haras un loop para llenar los botones, puedes aprovecharlo y usarlo para su creación. Puedes tomar como referencia lo del link que mandas, pero lo que esta ahi no es dinámico. Dinámico seria que se creen los botones segun la cantidad de elementos que tiene tu fuente de datos, en este caso TeamFCH.